# HTML5 boilerplate

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

A few days ago I learnt about `HTML5` boilerplates so I'm fairly a novice. I'm trying to experiment with boilerplates so I went ahead and downloaded this [boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/)

But I'm confused between the differences of the download options.

There is a button for a  ready customized files download and there is a custom build. I downloaded the ready customized and the responsive one from "Get a custom build", but I don't really get the difference between them and does the "ready customized files" support responsive devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ready customized files, is just a plain html layout with no responsive framework or plugin. The get custom build allows you to choose a bootstrap template that has some responsive components on it. ex(Navbar)

---

I suggest if you are using atom text editor to download this plugin https://atom.io/packages/atom-bootstrap4#templates.

Comment: What is the difference between the three main versions in the custom build ?

Comment: 1.The classic is just a html page with a hello world on it not responsive. 2.The Responsive is using css media queries to make the page responsive on all devices. 
3. Bootstrap is a framework that does all the work for you all you do is specify the components you want and the devices screen size you want it respond to.

Answer (score 1):

"There is a button for a ready customized files download and there is a custom build. I downloaded the ready customized and the responsive one from "Get a custom build", but I don't really get the difference between them and does the "ready customized files" support responsive devices ?"

Yes. The ready customized zip supports responsive devices!